# How long are Steam Keys normally valid for?

Tags: steam

I was thinking on buying [Sono Hanabira on Mangagamer](https://www.mangagamer.com/detail.php?goods_type=1&product_code=149) (Potential NSFW Warning for adds) to support English localization of Shoujo Ai/Yuri titles, but much to my disappointment it's digital only so i would only be buying a Steam Key.

Since i do not have Steam installed but i do have an account (uninstalled Steam because it was more or less useless to me) i was wondering how long a Steam Key is valid for, if it ever expires.

Comment: I vote to close this question, because it is too broad. It depends on the key and the developer. Your only chance is to ask the seller of the key if they plan on using a timelimit. https://www.reddit.com/r/patientgamers/comments/3dxpzs/psa_be_wary_of_expiring_steam_keys_in_humble/

Comment: Can't you redeem the key even without Steam installed by going to the site?  Then the game will be part of your library forever, even if the key would become invalid for some reason.

Comment: @gatherer818 No, there is no way to redeem it without the client right now.

Comment: @BulliedByMods Asking how long a key is valid for sounds pretty relevant to me.  Steam is Steam; how it works for one game should be valid across the board, because it's going to be a Steam policy, not a game specific one.

Comment: @Frank But it is game specific, if we are talking about actual keys and not just items acquired on steam, because people tend to call that keys too even though they are not really keys. There are time limited keys, even though nobody wants to believe it and as I pointed it out multiple times, they are mainly used for giveaways. This question is still to broad and you could also close with developer intent.

Comment: @BulliedByMods If they are time limited, what proof do you have?  If you've pointed this out multiple times, then you must have some proof of some sort.  And reddit is not proof.

Answer (score 7):

Steam Keys bought from Steam never expire - you can wait as long as you want; even if the game is removed from the Steam store the key is still valid. However, there is no guarantee that Steam keys bought from third-party sources will remain valid for eternity. It would be better to use the key sooner rather than later if you do decide to buy it.

Comment: -1 because that is not true. Steam Keys can be invalidated after a while and has been done so in the past by Humble Bundle and other sites during giveaways.

Comment: @BulliedByMods http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/864973578010194714/

Comment: There is no conclusive/authorative answer in that link, however there is one here: https://www.reddit.com/r/patientgamers/comments/3dxpzs/psa_be_wary_of_expiring_steam_keys_in_humble/

Comment: That's not the only one I have. I can provide links to many sources that say they never expire. Admittedly there is no actual conclusive evidence for either side but the general consensus is that the keys can never expire. After all, if they did expire then the company who sold you the key would essentially be stealing from you

Comment: Also that reddit link is invalid since a) the game is not being bought from humble bundle and b) it suffers from the same problem as my own link - it is anecdotal "evidence" and cannot be relied upon

Comment: As I said, it mostly governs giveaways and therefore your answer is wrong.If you give a generic answer, do it right and add exceptions. This is a forum where experts are supposed to answer, not people with knowledge from badly researched internet links. Humble Bundle Keys did expire in the past and had a warning attached to it. If you don't want to improve your answer, fine by me.

Comment: I do not wish to continue this discussion unless you can be civil in your comments. You quote "badly researched internet links" and yet that perfectly describes the only "evidence" you have provided so far.

Comment: Agree with @BulliedByMods. Especially given that OP is asking about a key which appears to come from a secondary source. I sell some of these "secondary keys", and yeah, they expire.

Comment: @imulsion, if you buy a key brand new from steam, they have the fair understanding that your going to use it way before the key is even at risk of expiry. If you buy anything second hand, and keys are provided, you take deliberate risk that those keys have not been used, so it might come under "buyers beware". I know here in Australia, for example, EB games are able to sell preowned games that come with keys, and the warranty laws are stricter, here. I would consider "steam keys **purchased through steam** don't expire" to be possible.

Comment: @Timelord64 Thank you for the information. I will update my answer.